# O método find() da minha entityManager da DAO Generica está dando NullPointer, como corrigir?

Tags: java-ee, hibernate, jpa, vraptor

O alterar da minha DAO está assim:

```
private EntityManager entityManager;

public void alterar() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("T encontrada");
    System.out.println("iniciando Alterar id: " + this.getId());
    System.out.println("this Class" + this.getClass());
    T encontrada = (T) entityManager.find(this.getClass(), this.getId());
    System.out.println("encontrada");
    try {
        System.out.println("Iniciando a transacao de alteracao");
        EntityManagerControl.transactionBegin(entityManager);
        entityManager.merge(this);
        EntityManagerControl.transactionCommit(entityManager);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        EntityManagerControl.transactionRollback(entityManager);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // manager.close();
    }
}
```

Eu tenho registros no banco e estou com o tal registro gravado no banco mas no momento que declaro no Controller objeto.alterar(), ele da nullPointer no comando find a seguir:

```
T encontrada = (T) entityManager.find(this.getClass(), this.getId());
```

Como corrige esse erro?

Comment: Olá Thiago, tudo bem? Como você está construindo esse EntityManager? Você está usando VRaptor, certo? Se sim, usou o @Inject? Esta usando algum plugin como vraptor-hibernate ou vraptor-jpa? Nos passe mais detalhes sobre sua infra :)

Comment: @Turini na verdade, nao estou usando nenhum plugin desses, é um projeto Maven, com vRaptor, Hibernate e JPA 2.0, nos outros métodos como o de inserir e remover esta parecido so nao tem esse find(), estao rodando normal e vem a EntityManager.

Comment: Posta o código do método `getId`, deve ser lá o problema.

Comment: @JéfersonBueno, o código do getId():  `@Override public Long getId() { return this.id;}`

Comment: mas em qual lugar esse EntityManager está sendo criado, Tiago? Pode nos mostrar esse código?

Comment: a entity ta vindo normal, alterei e criei um metodo pra trocar pela find ta dando certo por enquanto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve injetar o EntityManager. Uma maneira mais fácil seria com a ajuda do Próprio VRaptor com a anotação @Inject

```
public class ProdutoDao {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager manager;

    public void adiciona(Produto produto) {
        manager.persist(produto);
    }
    //...
}
```

E ter em outro lugar uma @Produces ou usar o plugin JPA como pode ser visto com mais detalhes na [documentação](http://www.vraptor.org/pt/docs/guia-de-10-minutos/).